# Search in a list with argument

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I`m trying to implement a function that given an argument and a list, find that argument in the first element of the pair in a list

Like this:

```
#lang scheme
(define pairs 
    (list (cons 1 2) (cons 2 3) (cons 2 4) (cons 3 1) (cons 2 5) (cons 4 4)))

;This try only gets the first element, I need to runs o every pair on pairs
((lambda (lst arg) 
    (if (equal? (car (first lst)) arg) "DIFF" "EQ")) 
        pairs 2)

;This try below brings nok for every element, because Its not spliting the pairs
(define (arg) (lambda (x)2))
(map 
    (lambda (e) 
        (if (equal? arg (car e)) "ok" "nok")) 
     pairs)
```

The idea is simple, I have pair elements, and a given number. I need to see if the first element of the pairs (they are in a list) starts with that number

Thanks in advance

Comment: So how do you loop in Scheme?

Comment: With map or for-each ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Racket, this is easy to implement in terms of `map`. Simply do this:

```
(define (find-pair lst arg)
  (map (lambda (e)
         (if (equal? (car e) arg) "ok" "nok"))
       lst))
```

Alternatively, you could do the same "by hand", basically reinventing `map`. Notice that in Scheme we use explicit recursion to implement looping:

```
(define (find-pair lst arg)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((equal? (car (first lst)) arg)
         (cons "ok" (find-pair (rest lst) arg)))
        (else
         (cons "nok" (find-pair (rest lst) arg)))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(find-pair pairs 2)
=> '("nok" "ok" "ok" "nok" "ok" "nok")
(find-pair pairs 7)
=> '("nok" "nok" "nok" "nok" "nok" "nok")
```

Comment: This is almost what I need Oscar, but I need to say "ok" or "nok" for every element in the list. It would be something like "(find-pair pairs 4)" => "nok", "nok", "nok", "nok", "nok", "ok"

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida ok, I updated my answer. The question wasn't clear, it didn't specify that the output was to be a _list_. You should always add sample input / expected output to your questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme, you should usually approach algorithms with a recursive mindset - especially when lists are involved.  In your case, if you find the element in the `car` of the list then you are done; if not, then you've got the same problem on the `cdr` (rest) of the list.  When the list is empty, you've not found the result.

Here is a solution:

```
(define (find pred list)
  (and (not (null? list))            ; no list, #f result
       (or (pred (car list))         ; pred on car, #t result
           (find pred (cdr list))))) ; otherwise, recurse on cdr
```

With this your predicate function 'match if car of argument is n' is:

```
(define (predicate-if-car-is-n n)
  (lambda (arg)
    (eq? n (car arg))))
```

The above stretches your understanding; make sure you understand it - it returns a new function that uses `n`.

With everything together, some examples:

```
> (find (predicate-if-car-is-n 2) '((1 . 2) (2 . 3) (4 . 5)))
#t
> (find (predicate-if-car-is-n 5) '((1 . 2) (2 . 3) (4 . 5)))
#f
```